# Connect Spring Boot to AWS RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to write my Spring app to communicate with RDS PostgreSQL in this architecture, but I don't know how can my app communicate with something which is in private subnet
[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL8vx.png)

I tried default connection by host and port

Comment: how is this question related to programming?

Comment: why isn't it related to programming? I need somehow to connect to RDS with my Spring app, isn't it programming?

Comment: The way the question is phrased, it sounds like a networking-/routing issue, not a programming issue. If this is the case, the question might be better suited for [devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [su]. If this is not the case, then please [edit] the post and clarify the problem.